# Primary menu changes vertical aligment after opening search field

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a problem with my primary menu on WordPress website. Menu elements are aligned in the middle (vertically).

But after clicking search button (Szukaj) that opens the search box, menu elements are moving to the bottom.

And I have no idea, why it is happening. Nothing new appears while searching though inspector. I have tried to apply the same hight and width to the search button and search box, but that didn't help.

HTML:

```
<nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="Horizontal" role="navigation">
    <ul class="primary-menu my-primary-menu reset-list-style">
        <li id="menu-item-186" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-186"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/przewodnik/">Przewodnik</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/materialy/">Materiały</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-195" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-195"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/deklaracja/">Deklaracja</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-231"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/o-nas/">O nas</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">Co nowego</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-233" class="searchicon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-233"><a href="#">
            <button class="search-main-nav" id="formButton"><span class="search-menu-text">Szukaj</span></button>
            <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform1" class="searchform" action="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/">
              <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>        
              <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">      
              <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">    
              </div> </form></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="pl-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-27"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">PL</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-28" class="en-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-28"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">EN</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
ul.primary-menu {
  font-size: 14pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 150px;}

body:not(.overlay-header) .primary-menu > li > a {
  color:  #0f4d2f;
  text-decoration: none;}

.primary-menu > li {
  margin-top: 2.8rem;
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 3.5rem;}

button.search-main-nav {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  color: #0f4d2f !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: #eaeddc;
  font-family: Karla;
  text-transform: none;}

  button.search-main-nav {
   padding: 0;}

  button.search-main-nav:focus {
   outline: 0 solid;}

 .search-menu-text {
  font-size: 14pt !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
  font-weight: 100;}

 input#searchsubmit {
  display: none;}

 #searchform1 {
  display: none;}

 input#s {
  color: #0f4d2f;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: #eaeddc;
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-left: 0 solid;
  border-right: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0f4d2f;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;}

input#s:focus {
  outline: 0 solid;}

.searchicon{
 background-image: url(img/SZUKAJ-04_cropped.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 1% 16%;
 background-size: 1em;
 padding-left: 1.75em;}

li.pl-icon {
 font-size: 9pt;
 background-color: #0f4d2f;
 padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
 border: solid 1px;
 border-color: #0f4d2f;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 0.5rem;}

#menu-item-27 {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 45px;
 right: 83px;}

#menu-item-28 {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 45px;
 right: 35px;}

li.en-icon {
 font-size: 9pt;
 padding: 12px 13px 12px 13px;
 border: solid 1px;
 border-color: #0f4d2f;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-left: 0.5rem;
 margin-right: 0.2rem;
 margin-bottom: 0.1rem;}
```

JS:

```
$("#formButton").click(function(){
    $("#formButton").hide();
    $("#searchform1").show();
});
```

I guess the problem is in JS code, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#searchform1` needs to be an inline-block when shown, to align with the elements before it. Since it's hidden with `display: none` before the button is clicked, you have to add the conversion to the jQuery script to change it to `display: inline-block`. I mean this line (last part replaces the previously used `show()`):

```
$("#searchform1").css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Please note: Here in the snippet obviously a lot of the original CSS is missing (i.e. especially the part that displays the list horizontally), plus the width of the snippet is too narrow to allow the search line to fit in one line with its label. If you view it in a wider window, label and searchline are aligned, as it should also be the case when the full original CSS is loaded.

```js
$("#formButton").click(function() {
  $("#formButton").hide();
  $("#searchform1").css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

```css
ul.primary-menu {
  font-size: 14pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

body:not(.overlay-header) .primary-menu>li>a {
  color: #0f4d2f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.primary-menu>li {
  margin-top: 2.8rem;
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 3.5rem;
}

button.search-main-nav {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  color: #0f4d2f !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: #eaeddc;
  font-family: Karla;
  text-transform: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

button.search-main-nav {
  padding: 0;
}

button.search-main-nav:focus {
  outline: 0 solid;
}

.search-menu-text {
  font-size: 14pt !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
  font-weight: 100;
}

input#searchsubmit {
  display: none;
}

#searchform1 {
  display: none;
}

input#s {
  color: #0f4d2f;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: #eaeddc;
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-left: 0 solid;
  border-right: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0f4d2f;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

input#s:focus {
  outline: 0 solid;
}

.searchicon {
  background-image: url(img/SZUKAJ-04_cropped.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 1% 16%;
  background-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.75em;
}

li.pl-icon {
  font-size: 9pt;
  background-color: #0f4d2f;
  padding: 12px 14px 12px 14px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #0f4d2f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#menu-item-27 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 83px;
}

#menu-item-28 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 35px;
}

li.en-icon {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 12px 13px 12px 13px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #0f4d2f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="Horizontal" role="navigation">
  <ul class="primary-menu my-primary-menu reset-list-style">
    <li id="menu-item-186" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-186"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/przewodnik/">Przewodnik</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/materialy/">Materiały</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-195" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-195"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/deklaracja/">Deklaracja</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-231"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/o-nas/">O nas</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">Co nowego</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-233" class="searchicon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-233">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="search-main-nav" id="formButton"><span class="search-menu-text">Szukaj</span></button>
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform1" class="searchform" action="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/">
          <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
          </div>
        </form>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="pl-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-27"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">PL</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-28" class="en-icon menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-28"><a href="https://mozolewska.pl/kdk/#" aria-current="page">EN</a></li>
  </ul>
```

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Also, the `#formButton`, or rather its class `.search-main-nav` has a `padding-bottom: 20px !important` which disappears after the button is clicked and becomes invisible. That causes a vertical shift.

Try to apply `vertical-align: bottom;` to it. This will probably shift the whole menu, but it won't move again when the button is clicked, so now you can adjust the position of the whole menu.

Comment: It sounds logical but doesn't do the trick. The #searchform1 is now inline-block, but  whole menu is still shifted to  the bottom.

Comment: Please note the addition to my answer (at the bottom)

Comment: Applying `vertical-align: bottom;` did not help, but thank you for pointing out, that  `padding-bottom` disappears after clicking the button. I have applyed `padding-bottom: 20px !important;` to `#searchform1` and it seems to be working.